# What can a graduate student do in order to have a chance to stay permanently in USA upon finishing studies?

Tags: usa, visa, students

What can a graduate student do in order to have a chance to stay permanently in USA upon finishing studies ?

Answer (score 1):

Get a position at a recognized university. That way, you will be eligible for [employment-based immigration](http://www.uscis.gov/working-united-states/permanent-workers/employment-based-immigration-second-preference-eb-2). You need to have a permanent position, which usually means a tenure-track position.

It is sometimes possible to get permanent residency through the commercial sector, but usually only very large firms can afford having immigration specialists in the HR staff.